# Select INTO Temp table from dynamic sql string variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a procedure that builds out a dynamic SQL query simplified as

`@mySQLQuery = 'SELECT ' + @myCol + 'FROM' + @myTable`

I would like to select this query into a temp table to be used later in my procedure, but I can't figure out the right syntax.

`SELECT * INTO #myTempTable FROM ( @mySQLQuery) x`

is basically what I want to do.

I tried `sp_executeSQL 'SELECT * INTO #myTempTable FROM ('  + @mySQLQuery + ') x'`
within my procedure and that didn't work either.

Thanks for any suggestions`

Comment: You really need to start using `QUOTENAME` and protecting your sql from injection. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: No idea of it would work but have you tried replacing `@mySQLQuery` with the values from the original line. I assume that that SQL works.

Comment: Also, if you *are* using `SELECT ... INTO` syntax with a **dynamic** statement, the temporary table will **only** persist within the dynamic statement. Meaning you won't be able to access it outside of the dynamic execution of `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of you could achieve this would be to persist an object in `tempdb`. Temporary tables only persist for the **session** they are created in, meaning that if you create a temporary table using dynamic SQL, isn't only persist for that session in `sp_executesql`.

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT 1 AS one INTO #test;';

--This'll fail
SELECT * FROM #test;
```

Therefore you'll need to use a persisted table in `tempdb`:

```
DECLARE @NyCol sysname,
        @MyTable sysname,
        @MySchema sysname;
--Assume these are set somewhere

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@MyCol) + @CRLF +
           N'INTO tempdb.dbo.MyTempTable'  + @CRLF +
           N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@MySchema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@MyTable) + N';';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

--Do Stuff

--Clean up

DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.MyTempTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that I've used.

If the structure of your temp table is known in advance, you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (<column list>);

SET @my_sql = <your query syntax, without the INTO clause>;

INSERT #temp (<column list>)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @my_sql;
```

If, on the other hand, your table structure is unknown in advance, you can use a global temp table (`##temp`) instead of a local temp table (`#temp`):

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql <your query with INTO ##temp etc>
```

The global table (##temp) will be accessible from the procedure outside the `EXECUTE` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Scope of the temporary tables are only limited till the session is alive.

In your case, when you use sp_executesql, the local temp table is out of scope once the call to sp_executesql is finished.

You need to create global temp tables.

See below a small example:

```
create table dbo.test_mytable( col1 int );
GO

insert into dbo.test_mytable
select 1 union
select 2;
go

create or alter procedure dbo.test_myproc( @mytable varchar(255), @mycol varchar(255) )
as
begin
  declare @mysql varchar(4000);

  drop table if exists ##mytemptable;
  set @mysql = 'select ' + @mycol + ' from ' + @mytable;
  set @mysql = 'select * into ##mytemptable from (' + @mysql + ')  X';

  exec (@mysql);
  select * from ##mytemptable;
end;
GO

exec dbo.test_myproc 'dbo.test_mytable', 'col1';
```

When you run the above code snippet, you will see the result as below:

```
col1
1
2
```

Comment: This is a major SQL Injection problem. If you're using dynamic object names, use the right data type (objects use the data type `sysname` which is a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`) and wrap the name in `QUOTENAME` when you inject them.