# SQL join table with a dynamic database name

Tags: t-sql

I have a table which contains a employee ID and a database ID code in database DBX0 table 'FirstTable':

| Employee ID | Database ID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 456 | 2 |
| 789 | 2 |
| 149 | 3 |

The database name is stored in a different table 'databases' like :

| Database ID | DB name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | DBX1 |
| 2 | DBX2 |
| 3 | DBX3 |

So what I'm trying to do is join the first table with a separate table which is stored in the identified database, like

`SELECT * from DBX0.dbo.FirstTable a join (SELECT [DB name] from DBX0.dbo.databases where [database ID] = a.[database ID]).dbo.OtherTable`

(I don't think this will actually work with a subquery, but this would return the result that I want in theory.)

I have tried dynamic sql with a cursor to iterate through each database and then only return results based on database ID = database ID and Employee ID = Employee ID, but this returns the results in a separate result per database.

Also tried:

`Select * from (SELECT * from DBX0.dbo.FirstTable a join '+@dbname+'.dbo.OtherTable on a.employeeid = b.employeeid and a.dbid = b.dbid)`

in dynamic sql, but this didn't work either.

Is there any way to get all of the data in one result?

Comment: Can you combine all of the dynamic SQL queries into one big query string with `union all` between the `select` statements, then `execute` that string? That would return a single result set.

Comment: There are a lot of databases that exist so doing that would be too resource intensive I think.

Comment: You can `insert` the results of each `execute` into a (temporary) table: [Select INTO Temp table from dynamic sql string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58613310/92546).